# Will my attribute get assigned its default value if I use an initializer list?

Tags: c#, initialization

I've got a class like,

```
public class Revex
{
    public IEnumerable<char> AllCharacters = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(Convert.ToChar).Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray();
    // ...
```

If I initialize it with

```
var r = new Revex { AllCharacters = "abcd" };
```

Will that line above get executed or not (Enumerable.Range...)? If I want it to *not* get called when I construct my class this way, how would I do that?

I've got about 10 optional character classes like that, so I don't want to write a constructor for every possible combination of them.

Answer (score 2):

Initialised member variables like this are always initialized prior to execution of the code in your constructor.

In this situation, you have the following sequence

1. Initialize the `AllCharacters` member variable
2. Run the Revex constructor (which might be the compiler supplied default "do nothing" constructor)
3. Assign a new value to `AllCharacters`

If you want to avoid this sequence, you'll need to move initialization of `AllCharacters` into your constructor.

If you also want to allow possible override, you might need something like this:

```
public class Revex
{
    public IEnumerable<char> AllCharacters;

    public Revex()
        : this( Enumerable.Range(0, 256)
                .Select(Convert.ToChar)
                .Where(c => !char.IsControl(c))
    {
        // Nothing
    }

    public Revex(IEnumerable<char> allCharacters)
    {
        AllCharacters = allCharacters.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Update 3 Dec**

Another alternative would be to use lazy initialization to provide the default values only if explicit values were not provided by the class consumer. You'd need to switch to public properties instead of public fields, and provide logic in the property getters.

```
public class Revex
{
    public IEnumerable<char> AllCharacters
    {
        get
        {
            if (mAllCharacters == null)
            {
                // Default initialization
                mAllCharacters 
                    = Enumerable.Range(0, 256)
                      .Select(Convert.ToChar)
                      .Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)
            }

            return mAllCharacters;
        }
    }

    public Revex()
    {
        // Nothing
    }

    private IEnumerable<char> mAllCharacters;
}
```

Comment: The reason I don't want to move it into a constructor is because there's like 10 of these properties..that would be a pretty nasty constructor.

Comment: Lazy initialization may be a viable alternative. I'll update the answer with details.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
var r = new Revex { AllCharacters = "abcd" };
```

Is syntactic sugar for

```
var r = new Revex();
r.AllCharacters = "abcd";
```

It should be obvious that the AllCharacters field will be initialized to the default value.

If you don't want the default value you can do this

```
public class Revex{

  public IEnumerable<char> AllCharacters;

  public Revex(){
     AllCharacters = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(Convert.ToChar).Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray()
  }

  public Revex(IEnumerable<char> allCharacters){
    AllCharacters = allCharacters;
  }

}
```

---

There's one more option which is this:

```
public class Regex{

    private static IEnumerable<char> DefaultAllCharacters(){ return Enumerable.Range.. }

    private IEnumerable<char> allCharacters;

    public IEnumerable<char> AllCharacters{
        get { return allCharacters ?? (allCharacters = DefaultAllCharacters()); }
        set { allCharacters = value; }
    }

}
```

Here you lazily initialize the property value if it hasn't already been set.  So you don't pay  the upfront cost of setting the value if it hasn't been set, but you pay it later once the object is created.

Comment: Is there a way w/out the explicit constructor? I've got about 10 character classes like that, all optional...

Comment: Yes, separate out building to another class so you do something like `var revex = Revex.Builder().WithAllCharacters(...).Build()`.

Comment: Eww...that's nasty. I'll take the minor performance hit if that's the case.

Comment: I never said it was nice!  There's one more option you can do, I'll update my post.

Comment: There you go.  Lazily initializing the properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you initialise a class variable with it's declaration, the initialisation will happen. So in this case your field will get set twice, once as the class is created and then again when you set the property.

If you want the initialisation to be optional then you need to declare it as:

```
public IEnunerable<char> AllCharacters;
```

you will then need to initialise it in your constructor or as you have done by setting the property.